# Linux: Voltage and current regulator framework

Tags: linux-kernel

When configuring the new 4.5 kernel, several questions arose regarding the "Linux voltage and current regulator framework". Of course I read the config help text and have a clue about what it does, but:

What happens to my system if I build a kernel without support for this?
How can I find out which type of voltage regulator Chip my T400 has?

Answer (score 1):

In linux VREGs can be controlled for power saving and useful during system integration and in driver probe initialization.

If you build kernel without regulators, you aren't using the framework, which means you cannot enable/disable the regulator when certain peripheral are not in use (in order to save power).

Basically PMIC chip will have a regulator driver on linux which talks to your SoC.  And you can control them(on/off) with the help of regulator consumer driver.

Comment: THX - now I understand better. So how can I find which regulator chip my notebook has?

Comment: You need to take a look at your Notebook's schematics. But /sys/kernel/debug/regulator/ will have some userspace API to access the regulator. This will list different regulators and there is consumers node in each regulator/ which consumer driver get the supply from.